# Ubuntu 18.04 unable to play video and audio files

Tags: git, audio, video, ubuntu-18.04, git-lfs

I am trying to access the [CREMA-D Dataset](https://github.com/CheyneyComputerScience/CREMA-D). I tried the following two ways in order to access the files in the dataset :

1. I cloned it by typing the following command :

```
git clone "https://github.com/CheyneyComputerScience/CREMA-D.git"
```

2. I just downloaded the `.zip` folder.

In either ways I was unable to play the audio ( *.mp3, *wav ) or video files ( *.flv ).

It always gave the following error :

[image]

However if I individually download the file by visiting file respective page as shown below, I am able to run the files without any issues.

[image]

A few [answers](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-video-audio-codecs-on-ubuntu-18-10-18-04-16-04-lts/) on the internet suggested to install codecs by running the following commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Even after doing so I could not play the video or audio files.

The repository makes use of `git-lfs` in order to store the files. It clearly states

```
 If you just download the zip file (~24MB zipped, ~163MB unzipped) then all of the video and audio files will just be links to the git-lfs file.
```

I guess this is the main issue why I am not able to play the files. Although I do not know how to get around this issue of the files being file pointers rather than actual file themselves.

Could someone please help me to know how do I get access to these files appropriately ?

Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was due to the files actually being file pointers themselves. When I installed `git-lfs` and cloned the repository via that, it all worked.